# Imagen responsive en div

Tags: html5, css3

Quiero conseguir que una imagen sea responsive sin tener que ajustar el ancho y el alto.

```css
 body {
            background-color: #FDFDFD;
        }

        img {
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
        }

        .grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-auto-rows: 230;
            background-color: #F4F4F4;
            grid-gap: 10px;
            justify-content: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .item {
            background-color: #E9E6E6;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
            box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #888888;
        }

        .item:hover {
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #636262;
        }

        .img {
            padding: 0 15px;
        }

        .flex-box {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        .tweet {
            margin-left: auto;
            align-self: center;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

            .item,
            .item1 {
                grid-template-columns: 1fr;
                grid-auto-rows: 230;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
        <div class="item item1">
            <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/480?random=1" alt="01">
            <div class="img">
                <h3>Header1</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam explicabo distinctio placeat
                    voluptas, tempora at iure libero aut provident velit similique ducimus inventore! Quaerat
                    voluptatibus consectetur adipisci sapiente eius delectus.</p>
                <div class="flex-box">
                    <p>Fecha<br><span>Autor</span></p>
                    <p class="tweet">Tweet</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item2">
            <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/480?random=2" alt="02">
            <div class="img">
                <h3>Header2</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam explicabo distinctio placeat
                    voluptas, tempora at iure libero aut provident velit similique ducimus inventore! Quaerat
                    voluptatibus consectetur adipisci sapiente eius delectus.</p>
                <div class="flex-box">
                    <p>Fecha<br><span>Autor</span></p>
                    <p class="tweet">Tweet</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item3">
            <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/480?random=3" alt="03">
            <div class="img">
                <h3>Header3</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam explicabo distinctio placeat
                    voluptas, tempora at iure libero aut provident velit similique ducimus inventore! Quaerat
                    voluptatibus consectetur adipisci sapiente eius delectus.</p>
                <div class="flex-box">
                    <p>Fecha<br><span>Autor</span></p>
                    <p class="tweet">Tweet</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo necesitas cambiar las propiedades `width` y `height` así:

```
img {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
}
```

```css
 body {
            background-color: #FDFDFD;
        }

        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        .grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-auto-rows: 230;
            background-color: #F4F4F4;
            grid-gap: 10px;
            justify-content: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .item {
            background-color: #E9E6E6;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
            box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #888888;
        }

        .item:hover {
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #636262;
        }

        .img {
            padding: 0 15px;
        }

        .flex-box {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        .tweet {
            margin-left: auto;
            align-self: center;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

            .item,
            .item1 {
                grid-template-columns: 1fr;
                grid-auto-rows: 230;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
        <div class="item item1">
            <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/480?random=1" alt="01">
            <div class="img">
                <h3>Header1</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam explicabo distinctio placeat
                    voluptas, tempora at iure libero aut provident velit similique ducimus inventore! Quaerat
                    voluptatibus consectetur adipisci sapiente eius delectus.</p>
                <div class="flex-box">
                    <p>Fecha<br><span>Autor</span></p>
                    <p class="tweet">Tweet</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item2">
            <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/480?random=2" alt="02">
            <div class="img">
                <h3>Header2</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam explicabo distinctio placeat
                    voluptas, tempora at iure libero aut provident velit similique ducimus inventore! Quaerat
                    voluptatibus consectetur adipisci sapiente eius delectus.</p>
                <div class="flex-box">
                    <p>Fecha<br><span>Autor</span></p>
                    <p class="tweet">Tweet</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item3">
            <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/480?random=3" alt="03">
            <div class="img">
                <h3>Header3</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam explicabo distinctio placeat
                    voluptas, tempora at iure libero aut provident velit similique ducimus inventore! Quaerat
                    voluptatibus consectetur adipisci sapiente eius delectus.</p>
                <div class="flex-box">
                    <p>Fecha<br><span>Autor</span></p>
                    <p class="tweet">Tweet</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo aqui te aporto 2  soluciones

1. utilizar el  atributo srcset

```html
<img srcset="elva-fairy-320w.jpg 320w,
             elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
             elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px,
            (max-width: 480px) 440px,
            800px"
     src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg" alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

2. Utilizar los Media Queries.

```html
@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px), (min-width: 1151px) {
  img {
    width: 700px;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```